# Pipenv: Specify local version of python package in pipfile

Tags: pipenv, pipfile

I have a pipfile that looks something like this:

```
[packages]
pyarrow = "*"
tensorflow = "==1.8.0"
h5py = "*"
```

I have another package, `xyz`, that exists in a github repo.  I've cloned that repo, made some edits to it, and now want to include the *edited* version in my pipfile.  If it helps, I also have the modified version of `xyz` in a branch on Github.

How might I do this?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to reference the dependency by path:

```
[packages]
xyz = {path = '../xyz',editable = true}
```

Then:

```
pipenv --rm
pipenv lock
pipenv install
```

I hit an issue where path is limited to 8 chars or something like that. My workaround was to to a softlink to the real package location so that it fits in those 8 chars.